# css3 after is on the text in a element

Tags: html, css

My problem is that the `:after` element is on the text in an element. Here is an example:

[On CodePen](https://codepen.io/Amirtvs/pen/KyWLEb)

I want the `:after` to be below the text.

How can I fix this?

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #222;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #00A3A3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `top:0` to `top:50px;` in `after` css. By keeping `top:0`

The top property sets the top edge of an element to a unit above/below the top edge of its nearest positioned ancestor.

you are making the element to stay on the top by keeping it 0

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #222;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #00A3A3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home page</a>
```

Comment: you are so smart:|

Answer (score 0):

Use `top: 100%` on the `:after` pseudo element to place it exactly below the main element.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #222;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #00A3A3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home page</a>
```